# How can I get an inner exception message out of a JSON string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have error messages that look like this:

```
var data = 
{"message":"An error has occurred.",
 "exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
 "exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException",
 "innerException":{
    "message":"An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
    "exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException",
    "innerException":{
         "message":"An error has occurred.",
         "exceptionMessage":"Message 1"}
  }
}
```

or

```
var data = 
{"message":"An error has occurred.",
 "exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
 "exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException",
 "innerException":{
    "message":"An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage":"Message 2",
    "exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException",
  }
}
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion as to how I could get the innerException message out of these two JSON strings.  The problem is that sometimes there is just one inner exception and the other times two. What I need is some way to extract the message from the most inner of the "innerException"

Comment: `data. innerException` or `data["innerException"]`

Comment: You'll need a recursive function or a loop, added an answer to illustrate the loop as it's probably simpler.

Comment: Those are not JSON strings. Those are object literals, they don't need to be parsed any more.

Comment: Are you sure about the data `innerException` within `innerException`?

Comment: @Praveen: Yes innerException can keep on going containing further Exceptions. Haven't seen many above 4 levels though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a simple loop should do it:

```
var item = data;
while(item.innerException !== undefined) {
   item = item.innerException;
}
var msg = item.message;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive solution as well:

```
function getMostInnerMessage(json) {
    if (json.innerException){
        return getMostInnerMessage(json.innerException);
    }
    else{
        return json.message;
    }
}
```

Comment: This post has been automatically flagged as low-quality because there's no explanation what this code excerpt does.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with three lines and extending `Object` type:

```
/**
* Return the last innerException (more down) for ALL objects.
**/
Object.prototype.getInnerException = function(){
    if( typeof this.innerException !== 'undefined' ) // Check if has a innerException
        var innerException = this.innerException.getInnerException(); // Re-call

    // You could throw a Exception if it's the first level and ir hasn't an innerException.

    return innerException || this; // Return the the next innerException or the actual
};
```

Now you can get the last innerException (more down) calling to the `Object` method:

```
//Object {message: "An error has occurred.", exceptionMessage: "Message 1"}
console.log(data.getInnerException());
//Object {message: "An error has occurred.", exceptionMessage: "Message 2", exceptionType: "System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException"}
console.log(data2.getInnerException());
```

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6j3ecp8/2/

Comment: Really?! You'd extend the Object type for something as specific as getting an innerException? It's not applicable 99% of the time so why should it sit on an Object?

Comment: Data is a `Object` and need a `innerException` method. Also you can do other type like CustomException and add the method to it. You only need extend when need get the `innterException`. The correct is create a type for the exceptions but it isn't the question here. If you prefer you could change the method to a function, although I don't like but it's same.

Comment: Extending the Object prototype is a really bad idea. In most situations, it's fine, but then one day it will come back and bite you. Extending Error is better.